# Can't import sklearn.qda and sklearn.lda with scikit-learn 0.19.1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can't import sklearn.qda and sklearn.lda with scikit-learn  0.19.1

I get:
    ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.qda'
    ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.lda'

---

Update:

```
import sklearn.discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
```

gives:

```
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis'; 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis' is not a package
```

import sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
gives:

```
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis'; 'sklearn.discriminant_analysis' is not a package
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have been moved to a new package [discriminant_analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.discriminant_analysis).

Try:

To import the module:

```
import sklearn.discriminant_analysis
```

To import the classes:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
```

If you had earlier versions of sklearn (possibly 0.17 or 0.18), you would have gotten a `deprecated` warning for them. But they have been removed in 0.19.

Please see here to see the deprecation information:

- http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.qda.QDA.html

Comment: @ronseg Aah yes, my bad. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I will upvote in the future , can't do it now due to reputation limitation.

Comment: @ronseg You can accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

I had some code that called 'LDA' and 'QDA' and got those errors. I changed the import statements as shown

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis as QDA
```

and the code now runs as originally intended.
Original code location:
[SKLearn Classifier Comparison](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/plot_classifier_comparison.html)